# Binding to a Combo Box not working

Tags: wpf

I have the following Combo box binding which was within a WPF window. I needed to create the window as a UserControl and since doing that my binding will not show the itemSource.

ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding CallerChoices}" SelectedValue="Sam" SelectedItem="{Binding CallerChoosen}"

The Item source CallerChoices is a List property on the .cs page.

Hope you can help as I have looked around and it just keeps showing how to bind to items stored within the XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if the datacontext or the source of the binding is set to correct source?

Does the Output window of Visual Studio say any Binding errors?